# Rescatar substrings desde cadena de un archivo pgn

Tags: python, string, substring

Tratando de ayudar en [esta pregunta](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34943/how-do-convert-parse-extract-data-from-a-pgn-into-a-spreadsheet-google-sheet-exc) en Chess Exchange, estoy recorriendo un archivo .pgn de partidas de ajedrez que tiene una serie de partidas de ajedrez con el siguiente formato:

```
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2020.12.09"]
[Round "-"]
[White "GMWSO"]
[Black "Hikaru"]
[Result "1-0"]
[CurrentPosition "8/1k1K4/2Q5/1N6/8/6B1/8/8 b - -"]
[Timezone "UTC"]
[ECO "B06"]
[ECOUrl "https://www.chess.com/openings/Modern-Defense-Standard-Line-3...c6"]
[UTCDate "2020.12.09"]
[UTCTime "20:25:00"]
[WhiteElo "3099"]
[BlackElo "3355"]
[TimeControl "60+1"]
[Termination "GMWSO won by checkmate"]
[StartTime "20:25:00"]
[EndDate "2020.12.09"]
[EndTime "20:29:58"]
[Link "https://www.chess.com/game/live/5927279266"]

1. d4 {[%clk 0:02:59.9]} 1... Nf6 {[%clk 0:02:59.9]} 2. c4 {[%clk 0:02:59.6]} 2... e6 {[%clk 0:02:59.5]} 3. Nc3 {[%clk 0:02:59.2]} 3... Bb4 {[%clk 0:02:59.1]} 4. e3 {[%clk 0:02:58.9]} 4... O-O {[%clk 0:02:58.5]} 5. Bd3 {[%clk 0:02:58.6]} 5... d6 {[%clk 0:02:58]} 6. Nf3 {[%clk 0:02:56.9]} 6... Nc6 {[%clk 0:02:57.2]} 7. O-O {[%clk 0:02:56.4]} 7... Bxc3 {[%clk 0:02:56.2]} 8. bxc3 {[%clk 0:02:55.4]} 8... e5 {[%clk 0:02:56.1]} 9. e4 {[%clk 0:02:53.9]} 9... Re8 {[%clk 0:02:55.3]} 10. Re1 {[%clk 0:02:37.8]} 10... h6 {[%clk 0:02:54.2]} 11. h3 {[%clk 0:02:36.4]} 11... b6 {[%clk 0:02:46.4]} 12. a4 {[%clk 0:02:27.3]} 12... Ba6 {[%clk 0:02:42.7]} 13. Bb2 {[%clk 0:02:14]} 13... Na5 {[%clk 0:02:41.3]} 14. Nd2 {[%clk 0:02:12.9]} 14... Nh7 {[%clk 0:02:35.3]} 15. Bf1 {[%clk 0:02:09.2]} 15... Ng5 {[%clk 0:02:32.9]} 16. Qc2 {[%clk 0:02:06.5]} 16... Qf6 {[%clk 0:02:31.8]} 17. Re3 {[%clk 0:02:04.9]} 17... Qe6 {[%clk 0:02:27.8]} 18. d5 {[%clk 0:01:55.3]} 18... Qe7 {[%clk 0:02:23.6]} 19. g3 {[%clk 0:01:52.3]} 19... Rf8 {[%clk 0:02:20.9]} 20. h4 {[%clk 0:01:50.3]} 20... Nh7 {[%clk 0:02:20]} 21. c5 {[%clk 0:01:45.5]} 21... Bxf1 {[%clk 0:02:12.8]} 22. cxd6 {[%clk 0:01:45.4]} 22... cxd6 {[%clk 0:02:12.1]} 23. Rxf1 {[%clk 0:01:45.3]} 23... Rac8 {[%clk 0:02:11.5]} 24. c4 {[%clk 0:01:41.9]} 24... Nf6 {[%clk 0:02:06.7]} 25. f4 {[%clk 0:01:35.2]} 25... Ng4 {[%clk 0:02:03.2]} 26. Ref3 {[%clk 0:01:32.7]} 26... Qc7 {[%clk 0:02:02.4]} 27. Ba3 {[%clk 0:01:18.7]} 27... Rfd8 {[%clk 0:01:54.5]} 28. Bb4 {[%clk 0:01:08.5]} 28... Nxc4 {[%clk 0:01:47.6]} 29. Rc3 {[%clk 0:01:05.7]} 29... b5 {[%clk 0:01:35.1]} 30. axb5 {[%clk 0:00:52.6]} 30... Qb6+ {[%clk 0:01:34.1]} 31. Kh1 {[%clk 0:00:52.3]} 31... Nce3 {[%clk 0:01:22.6]} 0-1
```

El usuario desea rescatar los valores `Date`, `WhiteElo`, `BlackElo`, `White` y `Black` y pasarlos a una hoja excel.

Al leer el archivo pgn **se almacena todo el archivo como una string**. He conseguido pasar los valores `Date`, `WhiteElo` y `BlackElo` a una hoja de cálculo con el siguiente código:

```
import pgn
import openpyxl
import os
pgn_text = open('ChessCom_gmwso_202012.pgn').read()
dates = []
welo = []
belo = []
def getValues(file):
    test_str = file
    test_date = "[Date"
    res1 = [i for i in range(len(test_str)) if test_str.startswith(test_date, i)]
    test_welo = "[WhiteElo"
    res2 = [i for i in range(len(test_str)) if test_str.startswith(test_welo, i)]
    test_belo = "[BlackElo"
    res3 = [i for i in range(len(test_str)) if test_str.startswith(test_belo, i)]
    
    for i in res1:
        dates.append(test_str[i+5:i+17])
    for i in res2:
        welo.append(test_str[i+9:i+15])
    for i in res3:
        belo.append(test_str[i+9:i+15])

getValues(pgn_text)

def generateExcel(dates,welo,belo):
    file = 'chess_games.xlsx'
    if os.path.isfile(file):
         wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file)
         print ('Via isfile')
    else:
        wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
        print ("Via is not file")
    ws = wb["chess_games"]
    for k in range (len(dates)):
        ws['A'+str(k+1)] = dates[k]
    for k in range (len(welo)):
        ws['B'+str(k+1)] = welo[k]
    for k in range (len(belo)):
        ws['C'+str(k+1)] = belo[k]
    wb.save(file)
generateExcel(dates,welo,belo)
```

Sin embargo, los valores de `White` y `Black` son nombres de distintas longitudes, y no se pueden rescatar usando posiciones fijas de la string.

¿Cómo podría rescatarlos para introducirlos en la hoja excel?

Comment: Yo no usaría posiciones fijas, sino un `.split()`, como por ejemplo: `trozos = linea.split(' "')` para romper la línea en dos trozos, usando como separador el espacio y la comilla. Así en un trozo te quedaría por ejemplo `[White` y en el otro `GMWSO"]`. Del segundo trozo puedes quitar las comillas y corchete final fácilmente, usando subíndices negativos: `txt = trozos[1][:-2]` Esta misma estrategia puedes usarla con todas las líneas.

Comment: @abulafia Update: It appears Mike Steelson has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345784/how-do-convert-parse-extract-data-from-a-pgn-into-a-spreadsheet-google-sheet-exc), with an example given here

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MX1o5qdy0K3gTMzbimUV3SmFf-0XPCSJ8Vz4IjI-8Ak/copy

It appears there's a problem when it gets to the case of chess960 only. Consider for example [this player](https://www.chess.com/member/dukov5): Replacing 'gmwso' with the player's username will yield a weird output. i imagine the output will be messier for mixed chess960 and chess

Comment: @BCLC I don't fully understand the problem, but I've posted an answer below which I think it is pretty general, as long as the format of the headers is `[key "value"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que una solución muy limpia y elegante podría ser la siguiente.

- Usa un `defaultdict(list)` para que las claves sean los diferentes campos que definen las partidas ("Date", "WhiteElo", etc...) y los valores sean listas que acumulen los valores de esos campos para diferentes partidas.
- Recorre línea a línea el fichero de entrada y procesa sólo las líneas que comiencen por el carácter `[`
- En esas líneas, eliminas el primer carácter y el último (que son `[` y `]` respectivamente) y lo que te queda lo divides en dos por el primer espacio que aparezca, cosa que puede realizar `linea.split(" ", 1)`.
- La primera parte será una clave del diccionario, y la segunda parte (tras eliminar sus caracteres primero y último que son la apertura y cierre de comillas) serán el valor a añadir a la lista de esa clave.

Todo lo anterior se implementa en unas pocas líneas. Para mayor claridad he escrito la función `procesa_linea()` aparte, que separe y devuelva clave y valor:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def parsear_linea(linea):
  clave, valor = linea[1:-1].split(" ", 1)
  valor = valor[1:-1] # Quitar las comillas
  return clave, valor

dic = defaultdict(list)
with open('ChessCom_gmwso_202012.pgn') as f:
  for linea in f:
    if linea.startswith("["):
      clave, valor = parsear_linea(linea)
      dic[clave].append(valor)
```

Cuando haya terminado este bucle tendrás toda la información de las cabeceras recogida en un diccionario y agrupada por claves. Ese diccionario podría tener un aspecto así:

```
{
    'Black': ['Hikaru', ...],
    'BlackElo': ['3355', ...],
    'CurrentPosition': ['8/1k1K4/2Q5/1N6/8/6B1/8/8 b - -', ...],
    'Date': ['2020.12.09', ...],
    'ECO': ['B06', ...],
    'ECOUrl': ['https://www.chess.com/openings/Modern-Defense-Standard-Line-3...c6', ...],
    'EndDate': ['2020.12.09', ...],
    ...
    'WhiteElo': ['3099', ...]
}
```

Este diccionario tiene mucha más información de la que originalmente pedías, pero eso te da flexibilidad por si más adelante decides que quieres más columnas en la excel.

Una vez tenemos este diccionario, convertirlo en excel es cosa de:

- Decidir qué columnas quieres de todas las que hemos recopilado
- Iterar sobre las claves correspondientes del diccionario
- O usar `pandas` para convertir tu diccionario en dataframe y luego usar su función `to_excel()`

En este ejemplo voy a hacerlo con `pandas`, y te dejo "como ejercicio" :-) que lo hagas de otra forma si lo prefieres.

```
import pandas as pd

# Convertir el diccionario en tabla es directo!
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

# Seleccionar qué columnas nos interesan es también muy simple
columnas_elegidas = ["Date", "WhiteElo", "BlackElo", "White", "Black",]
df = df[columnas_elegidas]

# De la conversión a excel se ocupa también pandas
df.to_excel("chess_games.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2):

Vale lo he obtenido. La máxima longitud del nombre del jugador en chess.com es 35 caracteres. He almacenado lo siguiente a "[White " y "[Black " y lo he cortado a la primera ocurrencia del caracter "]".

El código completo es:

```
import pgn
import openpyxl
import os

pgn_text = open('ChessCom_gmwso_202012.pgn').read()
dates = []
welo = []
belo = []
whiteLong = []
white = []
blackLong = []
black = []

def getValues(file):
    test_str = file
    test_date = "[Date"
    res1 = [i for i in range(len(test_str)) if test_str.startswith(test_date, i)]
    test_welo = "[WhiteElo"
    res2 = [i for i in range(len(test_str)) if test_str.startswith(test_welo, i)]
    test_belo = "[BlackElo"
    res3 = [i for i in range(len(test_str)) if test_str.startswith(test_belo, i)]
    test_white = "[White "
    res4 = [i for i in range(len(test_str)) if test_str.startswith(test_white, i)]
    test_black = "[Black "
    res5 = [i for i in range(len(test_str)) if test_str.startswith(test_black, i)]
    for i in res1:
        dates.append(test_str[i+5:i+17])
    for i in res2:
        welo.append(test_str[i+9:i+15])
    for i in res3:
        belo.append(test_str[i+9:i+15])
    for i in res4:
        whiteLong.append(test_str[i+7:i+42])
    for i in res5:
        blackLong.append(test_str[i+7:i+27])
    for value in whiteLong:
        posClose = value.find("]")
        white.append(value[0:posClose])
    for value in blackLong:
        posClose = value.find("]")
        black.append(value[0:posClose])

def generateExcel(dates,welo,belo,white,black):
    file = 'chess_games.xlsx'
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file)
    else:
        wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb["chess_games"]
    for k in range (len(dates)):
        ws['A'+str(k+1)] = dates[k]
    for k in range (len(welo)):
        ws['B'+str(k+1)] = welo[k]
    for k in range (len(belo)):
        ws['C'+str(k+1)] = belo[k]
    for k in range (len(white)):
        ws['D'+str(k+1)] = white[k]
    for k in range (len(black)):
        ws['E'+str(k+1)] = black[k]
    wb.save(file)

getValues(pgn_text)
generateExcel(dates,welo,belo,white,black)
```

Comment: Me alegro de que hayas dado con una solución que funcione, pero la veo un poco frágil, pues todo depende de que la información que buscas esté exactamente en los índices que aparecen en tu código. He puesto una respuesta que creo que es más general, además de usar un código más corto y simple.

Answer (score 1):

Esta respuesta es complementaria a las otras, ya que he observado que esos archivos `.pgn` tienen múltiples partidas dentro, por lo que si entendí bien, lo que quieres hacer es poner cada partida como una línea del archivo final de Excel, o sea algo como esto:

```
Date   | WhiteElo | BlackElo | White   | Black 
-------+----------+----------+---------+--------  
Fecha  | Num1     | Num2     | Nombre1 | Nombre2
Fecha  | Num3     | Num4     | Nombre3 | Nombre4
etc...
```

Tomé como fuente de datos la página [A year of PGN Game Files](https://theweekinchess.com/a-year-of-pgn-game-files) y usé aleatoriamente un PGN, [euroonccgpa21.pgn](https://theweekinchess.com/assets/files/pgn/euroonccgpa21.pgn), de los que se muestran.

Lo que se me ocurre para analizar la data es, inicialmente poner en una sola línea todo lo relacionado a una partida. En la siguiente línea iría la próxima partida y así sucesivamente. Luego se analiza cada línea para extraer los datos.

Empezamos haciendo eso:

```
src = 'euroonccgpa21.pgn'

data = []
new_line = ''
with open(src) as f:
    for line in f:
        if (line.strip() != '') and line.startswith('['):
            new_line += line
        elif new_line != '':
            data.append(new_line)
            new_line = ''
        else:
            pass # nada
```

Hasta este punto la variable `data` va a ser una lista de cadenas, cada una con mucha información, pero resumido sería algo como esto:

```
[
'[Event "European Online CC GpA"]\n ... [White "Rapport, Richard"]\n[Black "Horvath, Laszlo"]\n ...', 
'[Event "European Online CC GpA"]\n ... [White "Krieger, Markus"]\n[Black "Bacrot, Etienne"]\n ...', 
'[Event "European Online CC GpA"]\n ... [White "Shirov, Alexei"]\n[Black "Ferster, Fabian"]\n ...', 
... etc
]
```

Ahora se puede analizar línea por línea buscando las coincidencias con la lista `columns`. Si no existiera un valor, se setea a `''` para que siempre corresponda a la cantidad de datos por registro.

```
columns = ['Date', 'WhiteElo', 'BlackElo', 'White', 'Black']

spreadsheet = []
csv_line = []
for event in data:
    for col in columns:
        start_pos = event.find(col)
        if start_pos >=0:
            end_pos = event.find(']', start_pos)
            value = event[start_pos : end_pos].split(' ', 1)
            csv_line.append(value[1][1:-1])
        else:
            csv_line.append('')
    spreadsheet.append(csv_line)
    csv_line = []
```

Aquí la variable `spreadsheet` tendrá los datos de la siguiente forma:

```
[
    ['2021.03.27', '2763', '2183', 'Rapport, Richard', 'Horvath, Laszlo'], 
    ['2021.03.27', '2050', '2678', 'Krieger, Markus', 'Bacrot, Etienne'], 
    ['2021.03.27', '2662', '2149', 'Shirov, Alexei', 'Ferster, Fabian'], 
    ...
]
```

Esta lista ya puede ser escrita a un archivo. Si deseas, puedes guardarla en un CSV y de ahí se puede importar en LibreOffice Calc, Excel, etc.

```
import csv # Poner esto al principio del script

with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(columns) # Opcional - Cabeceras
    writer.writerows(spreadsheet)
```